# Network device not supported on default elementaryOS 6 beta

Tags: kernel, internet

it seems like my network device is not supported on kernels below 5.11 is there a way to update the kernel from a disk on key or something since my internet works on the windows 11 I dual boot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably the "easiest" way to do this is to use the Ubuntu mainline kernel PPA, but download the `.deb` files individually. If you want to download kernels for 5.11.20 go here:

- Kernel 5.11.20 from Ubuntu mainline PPA: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.22/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.22/amd64/)

You'll find a bunch of `.deb` files there, the ones you need are these files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.6M Jun 15 09:31 linux-headers-5.11.0-20-generic_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12M Jun 15 09:30 linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-20-generic_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Jun 15 09:30 linux-modules-5.11.0-20-generic_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48M Jun 15 09:31 linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-20-generic_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
```

Take note that these are the `-generic` versions and not the `-lowlatency` versions. Open a terminal and `cd` into the directory where you downloaded the `.deb` files and execute these commands in this order:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-*
sudo dpkg -i linux-modules-*
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-*
```

(Note if you try to install things in a different order they will fail)

Once this is done you can now issue a `sudo reboot` and once the reboot is complete verify that your kernel is updated by running:

```
uname -ra
```

Which should yield the result:

```
Linux vm 5.11.0-20-generic #21+21.10.1 SMP Tue Jun 15 09:14:45 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now that a newer kernel is installed it will stay installed until a newer one lands into the repositories used by Elementary. Once the newer kernel lands into a supported Elementary repository your system will automatically update to it like any other kernel and everything should continue to work.